# Make: why do I get error saying "no such file or directory"

Tags: makefile

When I tried my makefile, I got error saying that No such file or directory, but my directory is right there, what do I do wrong? Thanks.

my project structure :

```
dev |--- ev
    |--- display
    |--- install ( makefile is here, try to call makefiles in ev and display folder)
```

My makefile :

```
 MODULES :=ev display 
 SRC_DIR   :=$(addprefix ../, $(MODULES))
 BUILD_DIR:=$(addsuffix /build, $(SRC_DIR))
 x:=../ev                               ------> add temporarily just for test, 
                                        ------> the same error if x:=$(HOME)/dev/ev

 INSTALL_DIR:=EX Frameworks Add-ons
 INSTALL_DIR:=$(addprefix $(HOME)/EX/, $(INSTALL_DIR))


 vpath %.cpp %.java $(SRC_DIR)

 .PHONY: all clean

 checkdirs: $(INSTALL_DIR)

 $(INSTALL_DIR):
      @echo "INSTALL DIR"
      @mkdir -p $@ 


 define make-goal
 $1:
      @echo "start building each part"
      cd $@ && make -f Makefile_new.osx clean
      cd $@ && make -f Makefile_new.osx package
 endef


 clean:
     @echo "clean up"

     @echo "BUILD_DIR IS $(BUILD_DIR)"
     @rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)


   all:
     @echo "start build subdirectory"
     @echo "SRC_DIR IS $(SRC_DIR)"

     @echo "x is $(x)"
     $(call make-goal, $(x)))   ----> when it comes to here, I got error message
```

The error messages:

```
x is ../ev
../x:
make: ../ev:: No such file or directory.
```

I guess it is about relative path, because I call this makefile from Install folder, then $(x) can't be found from Install folder, but when I tried to make a folder named ev (Install/ev), I still got the same error.

I think it must be something basic I missed here, but what it is.

Thanks.

Update:

I am trying to build a project which includes several sub-projects. the structure is:

```
dev |---- ev
    |---- edf
    |----- dt
    |------af 
    |------Install
```

Inside of Install, I have a makefile, which is at the top level. The makefile in Install folder will call makefiles in other folders to build different subjects,

Ideally, I want to build every sub projects without touching sources. My sources include c++ and java code.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you're trying to do.  Also due to some indentation hiccups I can't be sure, but you appear to be defining a variable `make-goal` that contains a template for a make rule, then using it with `$(call ...)` inside the recipe for the `all` target.  That cannot work: you cannot create a make rule inside the recipe for another make rule!

The reason this fails is that the `$(call ...)` is expanding to content which is added to the recipe of the `all` target, so instead of creating a new make rule it's treating the result as a shell script.  The first line is `$1:`, and you passed in `../ev`, so make is trying to run the command `../ev:` just as the error shows you.

If you describe what you want to do at a higher level we can give you some ideas on how to do it.

ETA:

If you just want your `all` target to also build a subdirectory, there's no need for all this complex GNU make advanced capabilities.  That stuff is only needed when you get to guru-level makefile creation.  Simple "build a target after another target is finished" is the exact thing make was designed to do: nothing special is needed to do that.

For example:

```
.PHONY: all $(SRC_DIR)
all: $(SRC_DIR)

$(SRC_DIR):
        @echo "start building $@"
        cd $@ && $(MAKE) -f Makefile_new.osx clean
        cd $@ && $(MAKE) -f Makefile_new.osx package
```

This is still a pretty non-standard setup but I think it will work the way you want.  Remember you'll have to either move the `all` target up to be the first one in the makefile, or you'll have to run `make all` explicitly: make only builds the first target in the makefile unless you give it specific targets on the command line.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. The thing I want to do is compile resources from different folders(not touch resources during build).

Comment: So, I don't understand why you want to use `define`, `$(call ...)`, etc.  Why don't you just declare a rule and list it as a prerequisite of `all`?

Comment: hi, it's a copy from other makefiles which I try to learn to do the same thing (instead of compiling .cpp  files, I want to call makefiles in other folders). Can you say more about "declare a rule and list it as prerequisite of all " sorry, if my question sounds too naive or silly. Thanks.

Comment: the case is in each folder (a separate project) a separate makefile is called currently (several targets needs to be build in each separate project). If I list all of them in the top makefile, it is going to be messy. I hope someone can give some idea about how to deal with this. Please check my updates. thanks.

Comment: I really encourage you to NOT try grabbing examples from other complex makefile setups, until you understand makefiles or are willing to read through the GNU make manual to understand what you're cutting and pasting.  Instead I recommend you go through a basic makefile tutorial and get a simple makefile working, then try to extend it.  When you get to a point where you can't figure out how to do some specific thing, come ask about THAT thing on SO.